# Pass variable from one initializer to another

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to pass one variable from initializer to another initializer. But I can't find how to do it.

I tried set `application`.

```
application.foo = 15;
```

But in another initializer `application.foo = undefined`.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to do this, seems link an anti pattern? Also, `application.foo` might be `undefined` because of the order in which your initializers are called. You can [specify this order](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/applications/initializers/#toc_specifying-initializer-order) with the `after` or `before` props

Comment: Could you update with more info about your use case? Seems like there would be a better way to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify [initializer order](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/applications/initializers/#toc_specifying-initializer-order). So you can use services to store variable to pass between initializers.